# NHibernate composite key issues

Tags: c#, nhibernate

In NHibernate, I define a class and its mapping. I am not sure if the composite key definition and equals/GetHashCode are correct ?

```
[DataMember]
public virtual int EXCEPTION_ID { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public virtual int RUNID { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public virtual int ROW_ID { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public virtual string FIELD_NAME { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public virtual string FIELD_VALUE { get; set; }

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
   if (obj == null)
   {
      return false;
   }

   var t = obj as ExceptionFld;

   if ((EXCEPTION_ID == t.EXCEPTION_ID) && (RUNID == t.RUNID) && (ROW_ID == t.ROW_ID) && (FIELD_NAME == t.FIELD_NAME))
   {
      return true; 
   }     

   return false;
}        

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return (EXCEPTION_ID + "|" + RUNID + "|" + ROW_ID + "|" + FIELD_NAME).GetHashCode();
}
```

The mapping file is

```
 <composite-id>
      <key-property name="EXCEPTION_ID"/>
      <key-property name="RUNID"/>
      <key-property name="ROW_ID"/>
      <key-property name="FIELD_NAME"/>
    </composite-id>

    <property name="EXCEPTION_ID" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" not-null="true">
      <column name="EXCEPTION_ID" />
    </property>

    <property name="RUNID" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" not-null="true">
      <column name="RUNID" />
    </property>

    <property name="ROW_ID" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" not-null="true">
      <column name="ROW_ID" />
    </property>

    <property name="FIELD_NAME" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" not-null="true">
      <column name="FIELD_NAME" />
    </property>

    <property name="FIELD_VALUE" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" not-null="true">
      <column name="FIELD_VALUE" />
    </property>
```

Comment: You're not sure if it's correct? At a glance it looks ok. Have you *tried* it yet?

Comment: do we have to create a seperate class to map the composite key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather, you should **not** redeclare the properties outside the `composite-id` tag (see [example](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/antrad/archive/2008/02/10/how-to-map-composite-key-in-nhibernate.aspx)).

I'd rewrite the Equals implementation like so:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var t = obj as ExceptionFld;

    if (t == null) return false;

    return EXCEPTION_ID == t.EXCEPTION_ID
         && RUNID == t.RUNID
         && ROW_ID == t.ROW_ID
         && FIELD_NAME == t.FIELD_NAME;
}
```

because I'm fairly sure your current implementation would throw a NullReferenceException when called like this:

```
var instance = new ExceptionFld();
instance.Equals("");
```

when it really should just return false.

The `as` operator would attempt a cast from `string` to `ExceptionFld`, notice that the cast would fail and t would then be null.

I'm not sure about your `GetHashCode` with regards to performance or hash code distribution, but other than that, it looks workable.

Comment: You might want to check if it is null before cast. If `obj` is null, then the cast will throw an exception.

Comment: That's not true. Try running `object nullRef = null; MyClass test = nullRef as MyClass;` and see what happens. Now, it *is* possible that the parenthetical cast operator might end up calling some user-defined conversion that would fail on null, but `as` will never do that.